# Inkscape: batch processing (expand) SVG font glyphs

Tags: inkscape, font-design, script

In inkscape, I would like to apply a batch process to all Glyphs of a SVG font, like:

1. either just enlarge the path to make it look bolder
2. or, maybe equivalently, add a stroke, then stroke to path, ungroup them, union the stroke and shape

I can do this manually, but it is really tedious (maybe I want to test various stroke width…). Is there a way to create a script to do this automatically?